# How to change font family an input after selected

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to change `font-family` an `input text` when user selected it to enter sth.

now, Should I use `jquery` or `css` ?

default :

```
<input style="font-family:xxx" type="text" placeholder="test" />
```

after selected it to enter sth :

```
<input style="font-family:yyy" type="text" placeholder="test" />
```

Comment: add or remove  class depending on what you want.. where class contains the font family?

Comment: check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/e58r3zfL/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use css :focus selector

```
input:focus{
  font-family: some other;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use jQuery you may consider [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/), or the pair [.focusin()](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and [.focusout()](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/).

Answer (score 1):

May i help this css for you.

```
input[type="text"] {
  font-family:yyy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply some CSS to the focus of the element.

```
input:focus { font-family: xxxx; }
```